# I am new to SQL. I need in big query to add a column Duration with a calculation that is the diff of ended_at and started_at, and added

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to SQL. I need in big query to add a NEW column "Duration" with a calculation that is the diff of ended_at and started_at, and added to the existing table, I don't want to create a new table.
I am using:

```
SELECT 
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, MINUTE) AS Duration
FROM  `total_bike`
```

but this creates a new table.

I was able to create a new table with this, but I dont know how to include the calculation:

```
ALTER TABLE `total_bike`
ADD COLUMN Duration Int
```

How can I do both in one query?

Answer (score 0):

the ALTER table statement can be used this way to add the new column you want to add like this:

ALTER TABLE total_bike
ADD COLUMN Duration INT64 AS (
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, MINUTE)
);

Comment: I am still getting error message:

ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN does not support generated columns yet at [2:13]

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I found was to do it in **two steps**:

1. add an empty column to my table using this syntax:

ALTER TABLE `total_bike`
ADD COLUMN Duration INT64

2. Update that new column with the calculation:

UPDATE `testing-pancho-coursera.Coursera_Capstone_Bike_Model.total_bike`
SET Duration = (TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, MINUTE) )
WHERE TRUE;